# Spring service injection error when using mybatis

Tags: spring, spring-mybatis

when intergration with `mybatis`, I got `org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.test.test.sevice.TestService.getTestStr` when autowiring service interface into controller.But if autowiring service implemention everything goes fine.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    TestService testService;
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return testService.getTestStr();
    }
   /* @Autowired
    TestServiceImpl testServiceImpl;
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return testServiceImpl.getTestStr();
    }*/

}
```

full stack error

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.test.test.sevice.TestService.getTestStr] with root cause
 org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.test.test.sevice.TestService.getTestStr
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:230)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:48)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:65)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:58)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getTestStr(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.test.controller.TestController.test(TestController.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you share the full error stack you are getting?

Comment: @SunilKumar see above,thx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links and see if you are doing the same mistake.

[MyBatis Spring MVC Error: Invalid bound statement (not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081542/mybatis-spring-mvc-error-invalid-bound-statement-not-found)

[mybatis spring mvc application, getting Invalid bound statement (not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427210/mybatis-spring-mvc-application-getting-invalid-bound-statement-not-found)

Comment: have posted in the answer

Comment: It should be comment!